# Convention for methods declaration in Java

Tags: java, coding-style

Is there a convention in Java on where to declare fields - before or after methods?

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4649734/what-reasons-are-there-to-place-member-functions-before-member-variables-or-vice/4649844#4649844

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Class layout: see here http://java.sun.com/docs/codeconv/html/CodeConventions.doc2.html#1852

> The following table describes the parts of a class or interface declaration, in the **order that they should appear**
>
> 1. Class/interface documentation comment (/**...*/)
> 2. class or interface statement
> 3. Class/interface implementation comment (/*...*/), if necessary
> 4. Class (static) variables
> 5. Instance variables
> 6. Constructors
> 7. Methods

Comment: Hm.. From link you provided I see 1) documentation comment .. 5) Instance variables  7) Methods

Comment: Um... your list is completely different from the document you cite. And from any code I have ever seen.

Comment: @Stas Kurilin, @Michael Borgwardt sorry guys for the mess-up. Updated

Answer (score 2):

Most of the code I saw declared fields first, then methods (which is also suggested by the Java code conventions guide: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-141855.html#1852)

Answer (score 1):

Standard Java code conventions from Sun: http://java.sun.com/docs/codeconv/CodeConventions.pdf
And Oracle: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html

Answer (score 0):

Fields before methods is the most common style.

Answer (score 0):

I've mostly seen them at the top. One engineer I respect puts them at the bottom (to emphasize that you shouldnt be thinking about them :). You can avoid the Thinking About problem entirely by coding to interface, not classes. Also, take your vitamins. And floss!

Answer (score 0):

From most code I've seen, fields get declared before methods. This isn't set in stone, as some people follow the common C++ practice of putting public fields and methods first, and then private fields and methods. I wouldn't treat it as a strict guideline; just ask yourself what makes your code more understandable by another person.

Answer (score 0):

According to Sun's ["Code Conventions for the Java Programming language"](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-141855.html#1852), this is indeed the case: static fields first, then instance fields, then constructors, then methods.

However this part of the conventions is not quite as widely confirmed to as others: while using non-capitalized class names or capitalized variable names will immediately yield protests from the vast majority of Java programmers, many will accept putting fields next to the methods that operate on them.